# Debugging gf3/sandbox module

Tags: javascript, node.js, sandbox, node-inspector

I'm doing my baby steps in node.js, and i'm trying to understand sandbox mechanism.

Currently i'm using node v4.0.0 and node-inspector v0.12.3.

I've installed gf3/sandbox module and run it with this simple code:

```
var s = new Sandbox();
s.run('1 + 1 + " apples"',function(output) {
                console.log(output.result);
        });
```

In order to debug easily, i've also commented the timeout function in `sandbox.js` file:

```
// timer = setTimeout(function() {
    // self.child.stdout.removeListener('output', output);
    // stdout = JSON.stringify({ result: 'TimeoutError', console: [] });
    // self.child.kill('SIGKILL');
  // }, self.options.timeout);
```

The issue is that debug DOESN'T break on ANY line code of `shovel.js`, and i'm 100% sure the module is using its code.

Why is that ? And what can I do in order to debug `shovel.js`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sandbox.js` is [spawning `shovel.js` as child process](https://github.com/gf3/sandbox/blob/master/lib/sandbox.js#L44) without debugging enabled(e.g. no `--debug` option). So the child process executes normally and your breakpoints are simply ignored. You need to start child process in debug mode too.

If you want to debug both `sandbox.js` and `shovel.js` at the same time, then use different debug ports. I'm not sure about node-inspector, but here is an example of how you can do it with the debugger module. I'm sure you can tweak a bit to make it work with node-inspector.

1. Comment the timeout code like you already did
2. Pass debug option while spawning child process in `sandbox.js`. Note the port is `5859`:

   ```
   self.child = spawn(this.options.node, ['--debug-brk=5859',this.options.shovel], { stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe', 'ipc'] });
   ```
3. start `example.js` in debug mode. By default, it starts at `5858` port:

   ```
   node --debug-brk example.js
   ```
4. Now debug `sandbox.js` by connecting to `5858`:

   ```
   node debug localhost:5858
   ```
5. Once the child process starts, you can fire up separate terminal and start debugging `shovel.js` on port `5859`:

   ```
    node debug localhost:5859
   ```

For node-inspector, I think you need to use `node-debug` command instead of `this.options.node` for child process. Also [there are options](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector#options) to set debug port explicitly.

---

From above, These could be the steps for `node-inspector`. *Note: I haven't tested it*:

1. Same as above
2. Open `sandbox.js` file and change [this line](https://github.com/gf3/sandbox/blob/master/lib/sandbox.js#L44) like following to  pass debug option while spawning child process. Note the port is `5859`:

   ```
   self.child = spawn('node-debug', ['--debug-port=5859',this.options.shovel], { stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe', 'ipc'] });
   ```
3. start `example.js` in debug mode. By default, it starts at `5858` port:

   ```
   node-debug example.js
   ```
4. Now head to the browser to debug parent process:

   `http://127.0.0.1:8080/?ws=127.0.0.1:8080&port=5858`
5. Once the child process starts, open up another browser window to debug `shovel.js`:

   `http://127.0.0.1:8080/?ws=127.0.0.1:8080&port=5859`

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your detailed answer.
1. Where should I put this line:

self.child = spawn(this.options.node, ['--debug-brk=5859',this.options.shovel], { stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe', 'ipc'] });

2. What is "debug-brk" ? Why not just use "debug" ?

3. In paragraphs 4 & 5, Did you mean "node-debug" instead of "node debug" ??

Thanks.

Comment: 1. check the first link in my answer. 2,3:  My answer is for built in [`debugger`](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html) module. That's why the `--debug-brk`.    For `node-inspector` you need to use it's own commands and arguments but steps will be same. I'm on Windows and can't test since `node-inspector` doesn't play well on Window.

Comment: added untested steps for node-inspector. let me know if it works.